# Returning a matrix from a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix

How do I return a matrix from a function? I'm making a program that constantly sends a matrix to a function and also needs constantly to return a matrix from a function, I kindda know how to send a matrix to a function (with double pointers) but every time I try to call for a function it says that it is an incompatible type.
Here is an example of a function I use:

```
float *filtrar(float val, int col, float **M)
{
    int i=0,j,k=0;
    float temp[4][6],linea[6];
    if (existe(val, col, M)>0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<tam; i++)
        {
            if (linea[col]==val)
            {
                for (j= 0; j <6; j++)
                    temp[k][j]=M[i][j];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<tam; i++)
        {
            if (linea[col]==inferior(val,col,M)||linea[col]==superior(val,col,M))
            {
                for (j= 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    temp[k][j]=M[i][j];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the part that calls to that fuction:

```
float **m=filtrar(v1,t1,agua_vapor);
```

This last part is the one where I need your help, since I don't know how to give asigne the matrix obtained from the function to te variable m, I don't know if it should be as a pointe, a double pointer, a common matrix, etc.

I'd appreciate if someone could show me how to do it.

Here is the example of how I declared a matrix to work with, very similar to the one that the previous function showed was using in case anyone was wondering, how I did it:

```
float *carga_archivo(char nombre_de_archivo)
{
    float M[200][6];
    float *p[6], **q;
    int i=0;
    FILE *archivo;
    archivo=fopen(nombre_de_archivo,"r");
    while(!feof(archivo))
    {
        fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",&M[0][i],&M[1][i],&M[2][i],&M[3][i],&M[4][i],&M[5][i],&M[6][i]);
        i++;
    }
    tam=i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        p[i]=M[i];
    q=p;
    fclose (archivo);
    return M;
}
```

Any correction in may writing or way to ask this question is welcome.

Comment: return value of your function is of type float * , and you have declared m as float**

Comment: also in your function filtrar, from where are you returning from the function?

Comment: @HardikSanghvi I don't get the second comment, you are asking where the matrix comes from?

Comment: `float M[200][6];` declares a ***local*** array (to that function). When the function returns, the function stack is destroyed. Your compiler should be screaming warnings at you. You cannot return a pointer to a locally declared object. When the function returns, the memory it points to has been released. Either pass `M` as a separate parameter to the function, or dynamically allocate `M` within the function and then return a pointer to `M`.

Comment: So you are saying I should declare it as global? Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: It doesn't have to be *global* (in fact you should limit use of globals unless absolutely necessary). You just need to make sure the memory you are returning a pointer to still exists after the function returns. In the case of `carga_archivo`, `M` is destroyed when the function returns. So pass `M` to `carga_archivo` (or make it global) (or dynamically allocate storage for `M` (e.g. `float (*M)[6] = calloc (200, sizeof *(*M)[6]));` so it remains allocated after the function returns -- which you can return a pointer to as you have written)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, you are right, but when I try that last option (which I think was the best for this case) it sends me this  `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'float')`

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include the extra parenthesis in the comment above. it should be `float (*M)[6] = calloc (200, sizeof *((*M)[6]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a matrix you need to declare function as matrix type, I mean:

```
float** filtrar(float val, int col, float **M)
{
  /* stuff that filtrar do */
  return M
}
```